# django's HttpResponse is plain text and not HTML

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I am learning it for couple of weeks now. I have a .txt file that contains the HTML content i want to be rendered. I understand i'm not linking the css & js files properly. Can you help.

Project structure:

```
mysite/
   manage.py
   static/
      css/
        home.css
      images/
        logo.png
   templates/
      indexTemplate.txt
```

indexTemplate.txt

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/home.css" %}"/>
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.10.2.js" %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Header">

        <div class="HeaderLogo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Logo"/></a>
        </div>
    Nav1 | Nav 2 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 'u^37+&l60(xhoq8qyzlsyvynynpx%i-amg@@n#_x)tugfc5)61'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mysite/templates',
)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'myapp',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': '*********',
    'PORT': '8000',
}
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
```

views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def hello(request):
    t = get_template('indexTemplate.txt')
    html = t.render(Context({'mnu':'Trending'}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: I am doing this in an EC2 instance, if that matters. 

I've now taken out every thing from the template and rendering only an image. I've changed the static location in settings.py to /home/ubuntu/Desktop/mysite/static/ from /static/ .

Now the view source of my response page is <img src="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mysite/static/images/LogoV2.png"> STILL The image is not shown, only the alt text is shown. Where am i going wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
{% load static %}
```

in your template, somewhere near the top, before `{% static ...` tags.

And in your settings.py add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/mysite/static',
)
```

Make sure that really is the correct path.

Comment: Hey thanks. Added this as first line in template file. I still see plain text and no formatting. This is what the runserver console says: 


09/Feb/2014 11:06:58] "GET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1672
[09/Feb/2014 11:06:58] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.10.2.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1693
[09/Feb/2014 11:06:58] "GET /static/js/ShuffleAndDraw.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1696
[09/Feb/2014 11:06:59] "GET /static/images/LogoV2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1687

Comment: Hey sorry, I've missed a thing, see the edited answer.  But when you say you see 'plain text' do you mean normal rendered html just not styled, or you're literally seeing plain text (do you see html tags when you look at the page in the browser)?

Comment: Also, don't change `STATIC_URL` it was fine, you just have an extra ` at the end of that line (maybe just a typo here?)

Comment: I think that needs to be `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: `{% load static %}` should work if he's not using S3.  But since he's in debug mode, it shouldn't matter since he's just serving static files uncollected to production storage.  The built-in `static` tag works just fine with `django.contrib.staticfiles`.  OTOH, there's no downside to use `{% load static from staticfiles %}` either, so it really shouldn't matter which one he uses with `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's incorrect. As far as I know using `staticfiles` is the correct tag to use while `static` is for pointing at the directory. I'll have to look it up sometime later to know for sure

Comment: It's not incorrect, I have it working, in production, right now and had it working numerous times before.  There are two template tags with the name `static`.  The builtin one, to which I'm referring, and the one from `django.contrib.staticfiles`, to which you're referring.  The builtin one doesn't work with storage backends from `staticfiles` application, so for example if you use a cloud service for assets storage it won't work.

Comment: This is one area where the docs are just all over the place and horrible, these are not the only static related tags, and there are numerous ways to serve media and static in development, all documented but in a slightly different way.

Comment: Thanks NZP. Adding STATICFILES_DIR did the trick. My HttpResponse was un formatted text initially, as there was no linking to the CSS files. Now the styles, images are rendered. Thanks again ;)

Comment: "This is one area where the docs are just all over the place and horrible" - I  wholeheartedly agree