# Django application page not showing when deploying to pythonanywhere.com

Tags: html, css, django, load

My application works perfect when run locally on my mac os, but when it is deployed to pythonanywhere (and also on my partners windows os laptop) one of the pages just shows the html code instead of the actual page as shown below:
[image: webpage]

I dont know what the problem is as it runs locally fine. Here is my html page:

```
''' 
    {% extends "base2.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    <header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container my-4">
      <div class="border border-light p-3 mb-4">
        <div class="text-center">
                  <a href="/logbook/home/"><img src="{% static 'img/maplogbook1.png' %}" 
    class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container my-4">
      <div class="border border-light p-3 mb-4">
        <div class="text-center">
                      <a href="/logbook/create/" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">New Post - 
    Driving Instructor &rarr;</a>
                      <a href="/logbook/learner/" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark text-warning">New 
    Post - Learner Driver &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white">
                  <h2 class="card-title text-dark ">  <a href="% url "logbook:detail" 
    slug=post.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">New Post - Driving Instructor &rarr;</a>. 
    </h2>
                    <h2 class="card-title text-dark "><a href="{% url "logbook:detail" 
    slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.date }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Reverse around the corner: </p>  <p class="card-text">{{ 
    post.reverse_around_the_corner | safe }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Keeping to the centre of the road: </p>  <p class="card-text 
    ">{{ post.centre_of_the_road | safe }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Keeping to the speed limit: </p> <p class="card-text ">{{ 
    post.speed_limit| safe }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Watching your rear view and side mirrors: </p><p class="card- 
    text ">{{ post.watching_mirrors | safe }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Details: </p><p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
            {% for learner_post in learner_posts %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title"><a href="{% url "logbook:learner_detail" slug=post.slug 
    %}"></a></h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ learner_post.date }}</p>
                    <p class="h4">Details: </p><p class="card-text">{{ learner_post.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {%endblock%}
'''
```

Maybe it is a Django version thing ?

views.py
    '''
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .models import Post, LearnerPost
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from . import forms

```
def PostList(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('date')
    learner_posts = LearnerPost.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'logbook_index.html', {'posts':posts}, {'learner_posts':learner_posts})

def PostDetail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post':post})

def LearnerPostDetail(request, slug):
    learner_post = LearnerPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'learner_post_detail.html', {'learner_post':learner_post})

def PostCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreatePost(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/logbook/')
    else:
        form = forms.CreatePost()
    return render(request, 'post_create.html', {'form':form})

def LearnerPostCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateLearnerPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/logbook/')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateLearnerPost()
    return render(request, 'learner_post_create.html', {'form':form})
'''
```

Comment: Try removing `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No the same thing came back again.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657639/djangos-httpresponse-is-plain-text-and-not-html). If you are trying to run it on local machine check `settings.py` and set `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: No i have it running successfully on my local machine mac os, but when i run it on another machine or when i deployed it to pythonanywhere cloud this comes up.

Comment: Hey [this](http://jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook) is your project right ? After visiting that url I didn't get any plain text response.

Comment: yes, it is when you log in it does it comes up like this, it is only for one page which is why it is weird

Comment: can you share link of that particular page ?

Comment: http://jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/accounts/login/

Comment: http://jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook/ and then this is the page that does not show

Comment: Hey, over here `jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook/` remove that last `/`, use this link `jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook` it will work because we are rendering html page and that `/` means there is resource so it was rendering that file as plain text. I guess while redirecting you have put that `/` that may be causing issue check inside your code.

Comment: http://jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook just redirects you back to the homepage, when http://jonesl9.pythonanywhere.com/logbook/ redirects you to the correct page so i don't think that is correct.It should show a list of things. It is showing the exact html of the page it should be showing

Comment: Ok got it, I ran it on my local machine and it worked, I got some list. Now I know what exact page you want.

Comment: thanks, as i said it works on local machine like you got there so unsure why it wouldn't work when deployed. any help would be great thanks

Comment: How does your view function or class looks like?

Comment: I have added the views.py to the question there.

Comment: Something is making your rendered template be interpreted as plain text. Check the content-type header that your browser is receiving for the page. Then start removing things from the view to see whether any changes e.g. give an empty list for each of the lists in the view context. Then perhaps see if it's some middleware that's changing the content-type.